Can't connect to Postgresql running on docker, using Dbeaver
I set up mage-ai and postgresql containers via docker. I was able to successfully create the database during initialization of the container, could verify the existence of it via docker desktop. I wanted to connect to the same db using Dbeaver tool, but i keep getting authentication error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I will list relevant files below, to give you more content, and I am hoping for some lead.
Firstly, compose yaml file(local volume paths are simplified, dont mind it):
mage:
  image: mageai/mageai:latest
  command: mage start ${PROJECT_NAME}
  env_file:
    - .env
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment:
    USER_CODE_PATH: /home/src/${PROJECT_NAME}
    POSTGRES_DBNAME: ${POSTGRES_DBNAME}
    POSTGRES_SCHEMA: ${POSTGRES_SCHEMA}
    POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
    POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
  ports:
    - 6789:6789
  volumes:
    - C:/docker_volume/:/home/src/
  restart: on-failure:5
postgres:
  image: postgres:14
  restart: on-failure
  container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-postgres
  env_file:
    - .env
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DBNAME}
    POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  ports:
    - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"
  volumes:
    - C:\docker_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - C:\init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

AS you can see, I am using the .env file to import the variables, but i made use i stay consistent when trying to login, so that shouldnt be the issue.
I also checked the pg_hba.conf file to make sure that postgres allows for connections. It looks like this:
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

host all all all scram-sha-256

But still I get this when i try to connect using Dbeaver:

At this point, I dont know what to do, even mighty ChatGPT cant help any further, so I decided to go back to the roots. Thanks in advance

The error message is pretty clear, the password being used is not correct. This question needs more information, add as text update to question text: 1) Complete connection string. 2) Have you tried using psql? 3) Is there more then one instance of Postgres running? 4) If yes to 4) are you connecting to the wrong one?

The password authentication failure is a false error, as the request doesnt even reach the server, checked in the container logs. Thats the problem, there is no more context to share. No i havent tried with psql as postgres is not installed, thats the reason im using docker in the first place. Maybe thats wrong? Theres only 1 instance running of postgres. I am sure im connecting to the right one, the only one that is mapped to localhost


I'm betting there is psql in the container. 2) A connection is being attempted to some instance otherwise you would not getting the error as it is being sent by the server. 3) What log are you checking? 4) localhost is relative are you sure you are not attempting a connection to an instance on the host OS?


I figured the issue, it was as simple as the local port 5432 being occupied already by another service and therefore not being able to map to the container's 5432 port. Thats why I couldnt even see the attempt in the logs of the container, even tho when using psql inside the container, i could get them. Bottom line, it was a silly mistake. I am noob at network, so port mapping was causing me more trouble than it should have. I will answer the question myself in a detailed way and close it. Thanks for the follow ups

So, turns out I do have a local postgres installed and the port 5432 that i was mapping to the dockers port, was already occupied. I was sure I removed local postgres, but I must've dreamt it. I was able to detect the issue by running the following command in CMD.
netstat -aon | findstr :5432
Based on the output
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11084
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6188
  TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING       6188
  TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING       11084

I could dive in further and check which processes listen to this port using following commands.
tasklist | findstr 11084
tasklist | findstr 6188

As a solution, I simply switched to a port 5433 instead. I could connect to the database running on docker, from local machine.
